# Does it make sense to talk about smooth bundles of Hilbert spaces?

Tags: hilbert-spaces, dg.differential-geometry, banach-manifold

Is there a notion of *"smooth bundle of Hilbert spaces"* (the base is a smooth finite dimensional manifold, and the fibers are Hilbert spaces) such that:

> **1•** A smooth bundle of Hilbert spaces over a point is the same thing as a Hilbert space.
>
> **2•** If $E\to M$ is a smooth fiber bundle of orientable manifolds (say with compact fibers) equipped with a vertical volume form, then taking fiberwise $L^2$-functions produces a smooth bundle of Hilbert spaces over $M$.
>
> **3•** If the Hilbert space is finite dimensional, then this specializes to the usual notion of smooth vector bundle (with fiberwise inner product).

I suspect that the answer is "no", because I couldn't figure out how it might work...
If the answer is indeed no, then what is/are the best notion/s of smooth bundle of Hilbert spaces?

Comment: I would imagine that this would be a Hilbert module over $C^\infty(M)$: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_C*-module

Comment: Better to take a sheaf of Frechet spaces, methinks.  Or, take the base to be a measure space and consider Hilbert space bundles over that.

Comment: @Terry: Does your proposal satisfy my second condition? Is there some way to interpret  the notion of "fiberwise $L^2$-functions" so as to produce a Hilbert module over $C^\infty(M)$?

Comment: Why not just use transition functions in the group of isometries of Hilbert space?  I guess your question then is "what is a good notion of smoothness for maps from a smooth manifold to Isom(H)", right?

Comment: Also, what "smoothness" properties do you want?  Neither of your two properties has anything to do with smoothness, so you could, e.g. just take all continuous maps to Isom(H) as your set of admissible transition functions.  Of course, there are quite a few topologies on Isom(H) that you might take, resulting in different notions of Hilbert space bundle.  But I still don't see the real difficulty unless you give more detail on the properties you want this bundle to satisfy.

Comment: In particular, it seems that the fact that your base is a smooth finite dimensional manifold is irrelevant, so I'm still misunderstanding something.

Comment: @unknown(google): There are exactly two topologies on Isom(H) around: the norm topology and the strong topology (the latter is the same as the weak, as the ultraweak, etc... topologies). The norm topology fails my second requirement (about fiberwise L^2). The strong topology is perfectly fine, and there is a good notion of continuous bundle of Hilbert spaces. My question is whether there exists a good notion of smooth bundle of Hilbert spaces (that specializes to the usual notion of smooth bundle when the Hilbert space is finite dimensional).

Comment: @Andre: not quite, but I think functions which are fibrewise L^2 which vary smoothly with respect to the base coordinate (and in the fibrewise L^2 topology, after working in some local trivialisation) will be a C^infty(M) Hilbert module, using the fibrewise inner product as the module inner product.  (Well, ok, this is probably only a pre-Hilbert module, as it won't be complete.)  One could also start introducing vector fields as derivations, etc. in the usual manner.

Comment: How wedded are you to the ordinary definition of manifold? Some sort smooth space might be better suited for this task.

Comment: Maybe the following is relevant : 
http://arxiv.org/1004.4863 
"Uniqueness in geometric quantization" 
by László Lempert and Róbert Szőke
Roughly, they specify a smooth structure on a Hilbert field to be a C^infty(M) submodule of "smooth sections", and a smooth hermitian connection" permitting covariant differentiation of smooth sections along smooth vector fields.

Comment: @BS: Having a $C^\infty(M)$ submodule of "smooth sections" is indeed a good definition, but it fails my first requirement (about bundles over a point to be the same as just Hilbert spaces).

Comment: @Terry: I think that the notion of <<functions that are fibrewise $L^2$ and that vary smoothly with respect to the base coordinate in the fibrewise $L^2$ topology, after working in some local trivialisation>> is trivialization dependent. So I don't know how to make sense of that notion in the case of a fiber bundle without specified local trivializations.

Comment: Indeed the problem seems to be that for infinite dimensional Hilbert representations such as $Diff(F)\to GL(L^2(F))$ , $F$ a compact manifold, (implicit in your third condition), the subspace of *smooth vectors* is small (except when $\dim F=0$, of course). Indeed even for a much smaller (non discrete) structure group, such as $U(1)$, the same occurs. This makes the "fiberwise $L^2$ basewise smooth" condition trivialization-dependent: $(x,u)\mapsto (x,u\circ\phi_x)$, isn't smooth in $x$ if $u$ is only in $L^2(F)$ and $\phi_x$ is a nonconstant smooth family in $Diff(F)$. 

Comment: ...Citation from Lempert-Szöke article in above comment (p. 6, par. 2.2):
*In most respects, Hilbert bundles behave very much like ﬁnite rank bundles. However, the type of direct images discussed in the Introduction are rarely Hilbert bundles, and even when they are, it is impossible to prove this directly*. Here direct images are *fiberwise  holomorphic* $L^2$ sections of some holomorphic bundle on $E$, but fibers are non-compact, hence in general an infinite dimensional "Hilbert field". This is not a proof, but indeed points to a negative answer to your question.

Comment: Hmm, good point; one is going to need some inherent smooth structure to each fibre in addition to a Hilbert space structure in order to get the trivialisation independence. For instance, in the bundle example 2, inside each L^2(fibre) space one has a C^infty(fibre) space, and one can work with the pre-Hilbert module over $C^\infty(M)$ of functions which are C^infty(fibre) smoothly over the base, i.e. in $C^\infty(E)$; now we have the trivialisation independence. I think the completion of this becomes the functions which are L^2(fibre) continuously over the base. 

Comment: So perhaps one should work with pairs of spaces at both the fibre and bundle level - a smaller space of "smooth" functions, and a larger space of "square-integrable" functions.  The smaller space is where all the differential geometry happens, and the larger space is where all the Hilbert stuff happens.

Comment: @Terry: Yes, that's more or less the conclusion that I had come up with... But  if the base manifold is a point, then the notion of "smooth bundle of Hilbert spaces" is no longer equivalent to a single Hilbert space. It's equivalent to the notion of rigged Hilbert space, i.e., a Hilbert with a dense Frechet space inside it. My question is wether that feature is really inevitable...

Comment: The answer is yes also in diffeology because the category of Banach spaces is a full subcategory of the category of diffeological spaces. The general definition of fiber bundles in diffeology includes in particular this example. I didn't write down this example in particular, but I'm sure it works, for the structure you want.

Comment: @Patrick: "the category of Banach spaces is a full subcategory of the category of diffeological spaces"?? That's not even true in finite dimensions! (I like to have my maps between Banach spaces be linear)

Comment: @André it's a consequence of Hain's theorem a map $f$ from a Banach $E$ to a Banach $F$ is Banach smooth iff for all integer $n$, for all smooth map $P$ from ${\bf R}^n$ to $E$ the composite $f \circ P$ is Banach smooth. Ref: A Characterization of Smooth Functions Defined On A Banachspace, Richard M. Hain, Proceedings Of The American Mathematical Society Volume 77, Number 1, October 1979. (Theorem 1). Tell me what doesn't fit your needs. I am talking about maps $f : E \to F$ that are smooth in the sense of Banach.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**This is not an answer** but rather a comment to Peter Michor's answer. Anyway, I post it as an answer to get more flexibility in text formulation and to get more visibility. Namely, I think there is a crucial error which completely breaks down the argument so that generally *it is not possible* to perform the construction (**2•** of OP) of associating a fiberwise $L^2$ bundle over a given fiber bundle. The error lies in the following passage:

> That it is smooth $U\times L^2(F, vol(g)) \to U\times L^2(F,vol(g))$ is seen as follows:
> It suffices to show that $(x,f)\mapsto \langle f\circ \rho_x, \lambda\rangle_{L^2}$ is smooth for all $\lambda$ in a subset $\subset L^2$ of linear functionals which together recognize bounded sets.
> We may take $C^\infty(F)\subset L^2(F,vol(g))$ as this set. By one of the two smooth uniform boundedness theorems from the book below it suffices to show that for each fixed $f\in L^2$ the function $F\to \mathbb R$ given by
> $$x\mapsto \langle f\circ \rho_x, \lambda\rangle_{L^2} = \int_F f(\rho_x(u))\lambda(u)\,vol(g)(u)= \int f(v) \lambda(\rho_x^{-1}(v) ((\rho_x^{-1})^*vol(g))(v)$$ 
> is smooth.
> But this now obvious since $\lambda$ and $vol(g)$ are smooth.

Specifically, it is *not* sufficient to check "scalar smoothness" against the set of smooth (not even continuous) functions since it (generally) *does not* "recognize" bounded sets in $L^2$ . To give an explicit counterexample, understanding $\mathbb S^1$ as $\mathbb R$ mod $1$ , consider the map $f:\mathbb R\times L^2(\mathbb S^1)\to L^2(\mathbb S^1)$ defined by $(t,[\,x\,])\mapsto[\,\langle\,x(t+s):s\in\mathbb R\,\rangle\,]$ . If the argument in Peter Michor's answer were correct, then for any fixed $x$ in $L^2$ the map $c:t\mapsto f(t,[\,x\,])$ should be smooth $\mathbb R\to L^2(\mathbb S^1)$ . However, it is easily seen that it is not even once differentiable if for example one takes $x$ defined by $x(s)=1$ for $|\,s-n\,|\le\frac 14$ and $n\in\mathbb Z$ , and $x(s)=0$ otherwise, since then $\lim_{\,t\to 0\,}\|\,t^{-1}(c(t)-c(0))\,\|_{L^2}=+\infty$ .

Comment: You are right. Sorry, I saw your answer just now. A comment would have been visible to me.

Answer (score 23):

The answer is yes:

Let me sketch the proof. So $p:E\to M$ is the fiber bundle with typical fiber $F$ which is compact, connected (and oriented, for simplicity's sake), and you are given a vertical volume form $\mu$; so $\mu_x$ is a volume form on each fiber $E_x$ which depends smoothly on $x\in M$. First I choose another vertical volume form $\nu$ such that the volume of each fiber is 1, $\int_{E_x} \nu_x=1$. Take $\nu_x = \frac{\mu_x}{\int_{E_x}\mu_x}$, for example.

Now I construct the Hilbert bundle with fibers $L^2(E_{x},\nu_{x})$:
Fix a Riemannian metric $g$ on $F$ with $\int_F vol(g)=1$.
Let $U\subset M$ be open so that $\phi:U\times F \to E|U$ is a fiber respecting diffeomorphism. 
For each $x\in M$ the Moser trick gives us a diffeomorphism $\psi_x:F\to F$ depending smoothly on $x\in U$ with $(\psi_x)^*(\phi_x)^*\nu_x = vol(g)$. This uses the Green function of the Hodge decomposition with respect to $g$ to choose a $(\dim(F)-1)$-form $\alpha_x$ with $d\alpha_x = \phi_x^*\nu_x-vol(g)$ which depends still smoothly on $x\in U$.

Edit: 43.7 in the book cited below contains Moser's trick in the form I just described.

Then the mapping $\bigsqcup_{x\in U}(x, L^2(E_{x},\nu_{x}))\ni (x,f) \mapsto (x,f\circ \phi_x \circ \psi_x^{-1})\in U\times L^2(F,vol(g))$
is an isometric trivialisation of the bundle 
$\bigsqcup_{x\in M}(x, L^2(E_{x},\nu_{x}))$ over $U$.

Edit (more details): 
The change of trivialisation is then of a similar form, $(x,f)\mapsto (x,f\circ \rho_x)$
for smooth $\rho:U\times F\to F$ such that $\rho_x$ is a $vol(g)$-preserving diffeomorphism for each $x\in U$. 
That it is smooth $U\times L^2(F, vol(g)) \to U\times L^2(F,vol(g))$ is seen as follows:
It suffices to show that $(x,f)\mapsto \langle f\circ \rho_x, \lambda\rangle_{L^2}$ is smooth for all $\lambda$ in a subset $\subset L^2$ of linear functionals which together recognize bounded sets.
We may take $C^\infty(F)\subset L^2(F,vol(g))$ as this set. By one of the two smooth uniform boundedness theorems from the book below it suffices to show that for each fixed $f\in L^2$ the function $F\to \mathbb R$ given by
$$x\mapsto \langle f\circ \rho_x, \lambda\rangle_{L^2} = \int_F f(\rho_x(u))\lambda(u)\,vol(g)(u)= \int f(v) \lambda(\rho_x^{-1}(v) ((\rho_x^{-1})^*vol(g))(v)$$ 
is smooth. 
But this now obvious since $\lambda$ and $vol(g)$ are smooth.

The original inner product $\int_{E_x} f \mu_x$ is now a fiberwise Riemann metric on this Hilbert bundle.

I use calculus in infinite dimensions from:
Andreas Kriegl, Peter W. Michor: The Convenient Setting of Global Analysis. Mathematical Surveys and Monographs, Volume: 53, American Mathematical Society, Providence, 1997,
[(pdf)](http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~michor/apbookh-ams.pdf).

## Edit:

As TaQ noted in his answer, my proof above is wrong. In fact, the answer is no, if you accept that the construction which I tried is the natural one. Namely, in the realm of Sobolev spaces, if $k>\frac{\dim(F)}2$, for the composition mapping $H^{k+l}(F,\mathbb R) \times H^k(F,F) \to H^k(F,\mathbb R)$, left translations are $C^l$ and right translations are smooth; i.e., composition is $C^l$ in the right hand side variable, and is smooth in the left hand side variable. This is folklore; for a detailed proof see

- H. Inci,T. Kappeler and P. Topalov, On the Regularity of the Composition of Diffeomorphisms, Memoirs of the American Mathematical Society, vol. 226 (American Mathematical Society, 2013).

In the case above we have left translations, and no assumption for to be above the Sobolev threshold.

But if one asks for Sobolev spaces instead of $L^2$, one gets a $C^{k}$ vector bundle for $H^{m}$ with $m> k + \frac{\dim(F)}2$.

Comment: I wish I could upvote this more than once. :-)

Comment: I've done it for you David :-)