# Can smoothness of curves into a convenient locally convex vector space be tested with just a dense subspace of the dual?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, locally-convex-spaces, smoothness

Let $E$ be a (Hausdorff) locally convex vector space (from now on just "lcs" for short). We say that $E$ is *convenient* (also called *locally complete*, *Mackey-complete* or *$c^\infty$-complete*) if, given any disk (i.e. an absolutely convex and bounded subset) $B\subset E$ which is *closed*, the vector subspace $E_B$ generated by $B$ $$E_B=\bigcup_{\lambda>0}\lambda B=\bigcup^\infty_{n=1} nB$$ is a *Banach* space when the norm is given by the Minkowski functional of $B$ $$\mu_B(x)=\inf\{\rho>0\ |\ x\in\rho B\}=\inf\{\rho>0\ |\ \rho^{-1}x\in B\}\ ,\quad x\in E_B\ .$$ In other words, any closed disk $B\subset E$ is a so-called *Banach* disk. This is a rather weak kind of completeness - for instance, any sequentially complete $E$ is convenient.

It is well known that, if $E$ is a convenient lcs, a curve $\gamma:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow E$ is *smooth* (i.e. the iterated derivatives of all orders of $\gamma$ exist everywhere) if and only if $l\circ\gamma:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is smooth (in the usual sense) for all $l\in E'=$ topological dual of $E$ - see e.g. Lemmata 2.1, 2.2 and Corollary 2.3, pp. 14-15 of the book by Andreas Kriegl and Peter Michor, [*The Convenient Setting of Global Analysis*](https://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~michor/apbookh-ams.pdf) (AMS, 1997). This generalizes the usual concept of smoothness of curves with a finite-dimensional target by means of smoothness of each component of the curve.

> **Question:** suppose $E$ is a *convenient* lcs and $F\subset E'$ is a *dense* vector subspace of $E'$ in the strong topology $\beta(E',E)$. Let $\gamma:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow E$ be such that $l\circ\gamma:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is *smooth* for all $l\in F$. *Is* $\gamma$ *smooth*?

My expectation is that this is true if $E$ is in addition *semi-reflexive* (i.e. $E=(E',\beta(E',E))'$ as a vector space), for in this case $E$ is also the topological dual of any strongly dense vector subspace of $E'$, but I fear I might be missing something and there might still be room for counterexamples.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is a counter example. Let $E=\ell^2$. Consider the curve $\gamma:\mathbb R \to E$ given by
$$\gamma(t)= \Big(\frac{\sin(2^nt)}{2^n}\Big)_{n\in \mathbb N}$$
In the dual $\ell^2$ consider the dense linear subspace of all sequences $l=(l_n)$ with finite support. For such $l$ with $l_n=0$ for $n\ge N$,
$$(l\circ \gamma)(t) = \sum_{n=1}^N l_n.\frac{\sin(2^nt)}{2^n} $$
is smooth, but the prospective derivative $\gamma'(t) = (1)_{n\in \mathbb N}$ does not lie in $\ell^2$.

Positive results are the following:

(A) If $F\subset E'$ is large enough to recognize bounded sets, then $l\circ \gamma$ smooth for all $l\in F$ implies $\gamma$ smooth. See 5.22 of Convenient Setting.

(B) Theorem.
[Thm 4.1.19 in Frölicher, Kriegl: Linear Spaces and Differentiation Theory, Wiley, 1988]
Let $c:\mathbb R\to E$ be a curve in a convenient vector space $E$,
and let $\mathcal{V}\subseteq E'$ be a subset of bounded linear functionals such that the bornology of $E$ has a basis of $\sigma(E,\mathcal{V})$-closed sets.
Then the following are equivalent:

(i) $c$ is smooth

(ii) For each $k\in\mathbb N$ there exists a locally bounded curve $c^{k}:\mathbb R\to E$ such that for each $\ell\in\mathcal V$ the function $\ell\circ c$ is smooth $\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ with $(\ell\circ c)^{(k)}=\ell\circ c^{k}$.

If $E=F'$ is the dual of a convenient vector space $F$, then for any point separating subset $\mathcal{V}\subseteq F$ the bornology of $E$ has a basis of
$\sigma(E,\mathcal{V})$-closed subsets, by [4.1.22 in loc.cit.

Theorem (B) is surprisingly strong:
note that $\mathcal V$ does not need to recognize bounded sets.
One can use the theorem in situations where $\mathcal V$ is just the set of all point evaluations on a Sobolev space $H^s(M)$ with $s>\frac{\dim(M)}2$, $M$ a smooth manifold.

## Added, and later edited:

About your question in the comment. My counterexample was wrong. Here is the a  proof of the converse: For simplicity's sake I just take the real line:

(C) Corollary:
Let $c:\mathbb R \to C^\infty_c(\mathbb R)$ be curve such that for each  $t$ the the support $\text{supp}(c(t'))\subset K_t$ for $t'$ neat $t$ and a compact $K_t\subset \mathbb R$, and such that
$$t\mapsto \int_{\mathbb R} c(t)(x).f(x)\,dx$$
is smooth for every $f\in C^\infty(\mathbb R)$.
We also need to assume that $t\mapsto c(t)\in C^\infty_c(\mathbb R)$ is locally bounded. For this it is sufficient, that $t\mapsto c(t)(x)$ is bounded locally in $t$ for each fixed $x$, by 6.2 of Convenient Setting.

Then $c:\mathbb R \to C^\infty_c(\mathbb R)$ is smooth.

For an equivalent formulation of smoothness, see 42.5 of convenient setting.

Proof:
By the support condition and differentiation by parts,
$$t\mapsto \int_{\mathbb R} c(t)^{(n)}(x).f(x)\,dx = (-1)^n\int_{\mathbb R} c(t)(x).f^{(n)}(x)\,dx$$ is again smooth. Since $f\mapsto f^{(n)}$ is surjective, half the conditions of theorem (B) are satisfied. It remains to check that $t\mapsto c(t)^{(n)}$ is locally bounded in $t$ as a curve into $C^\infty_c(\mathbb R)$. But this follows from the condition for $n=0$ since differentiation is a bounded linear operator on $C^\infty_c(\mathbb R)$. qed.

Comment: Thanks Prof. Michor! The typical situation I'm thinking of is the following: Suppose $\gamma:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow E=\mathscr{D}(\mathbb{R}^d)$. I can even assume that $\mathrm{supp}\gamma(t)\subset K$ for all $t$, where $K\subset\mathbb{R}^d$ is compact. If $\gamma$ *as a curve into* $\mathscr{E}'(\mathbb{R}^d)$ is *smooth* (and therefore $l\circ\gamma$ is smooth for all $l$ in the dense subspace $F=\mathscr{C}^\infty(\mathbb{R}^d)\subset E'=\mathscr{D}'(\mathbb{R}^d)$), is $\gamma$ smooth? It seems to me that this fits into the hypotheses of Theorem (B)...

Comment: By the way, shouldn't the $n$-th component of $\gamma'(t)$ in your counterexample be $\cos(2^n t)$, so that actually $\gamma'(0)=(1)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\not\in\ell^2$?

Comment: I got it. If one uses a Valdivia-type characterization of spaces of smooth functions, one should be able to extend this counterexample to $E=\mathscr{D}(K)$ for any compact subset $K\subset M$ of a smooth manifold $M$, I suppose... Thanks again!

Comment: Hmm... Come to think of it a bit more carefully, I'm not so sure your example in $C^\infty(S^1)$ is correct - if the curve you wrote were smooth in $\mathscr{E}'(S^1)\cong\mathfrak{s}'=$ space of sequences with polynomial growth, all derivatives of $\gamma$ should be in $\mathfrak{s}'$, but this seems to fail for second- and higher-order derivatives.

Comment: OK, the last edit goes more in the direction I wanted. Another possibility, it seems to me, would be to use result (A) = Lemma 5.22, pp. 65 of Convenient Setting together with ibid., Theorem 5.24, pp. 66, since $\mathscr{D}$ is webbed. In this case, since $F=C^\infty$ separates points in $\mathscr{D}$, it should recognize bounded sets therein. I'm just a bit confused at how this compares to, say, delta sequences in $\mathscr{D}$, which are bounded in $\mathscr{E}'$ (since they converge therein) but not in $\mathscr{D}$.

Comment: You hit the nail: $C^\infty$ does not recognize bounded sets in $\mathcal D$.

Comment: I understand, but then how does Theorem 5.24 fare in this particular case? Does it have to do with the fact that the vector space $E_B$ generated by sets like (the bipolar $B$ of the range of) delta sequences is not complete w.r.t. the norm given by Minkowski functional of $B$ (see e.g. Lemma 5.22 (2), pp. 65 of Convenient Setting)? What is the difference between $F=C^\infty$ and $F=\mathrm{span}\{\mathrm{ev}_x\ |\ x\in\mathbb{R}^d\}$ in the outcome of Theorem 5.24 (as stated e.g. in 6.2 of Convenient Setting)? After all, both are point-separating subsets of $\mathscr{D}'$ in $\mathscr{D}$...

Comment: Another doubt came to me concerning the proof of local boundedness of Corollary (C): you have shown using integration by parts that the *$x$-derivatives* of $c$ are locally bounded in $t$, which is tantamount to show that $c$ is a locally bounded curve into $C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R})$, but how about the *$t$-derivatives* of $c$? Theorem 4.1.19 (2) of Frölicher-Kriegl demands that all $t$-derivatives of $c$ are locally bounded, and I don't see how one gets this from $C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$-smoothness (in the sense of Frölicher and Kriegl) and local boundedness of $c$ alone.

Answer (score 1):

$\def\sp{\kern.4mm}\def\bbR{\mathbb R}$A previous *idea for getting a counterexample* in the reflexive Banach case is [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/151509), and a modification of it is in the following: With $1<p<+\infty$ let $c:\bbR\to E=L^p(\bbR)$ be given by $t\mapsto c(t)$ where $c(t)$ is the coset containing the function $\bbR\owns s\mapsto{\rm e}^{\sp s}$ for $s\le t$, and $s\mapsto 0$ for $t<s$. Then $u\circ c$ is smooth for every $u$ in the dense subset of $E'$ formed by the elements given by integration against elements in the space $\mathscr S\,(\bbR)$ of rapidly decreasing functions, but $c$ is not even once differentiable at any point by the argument *loc. cit.*