# Connection on a Hilbert bundle

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, dg.differential-geometry, mp.mathematical-physics

Is there a well-defined notion of connection on a measurable bundle of Hilbert spaces?

Comment: If it did, then one could do differential calculus in an only measurable context. While some tormented notions of differentiability can exist in non-smooth settings (the metric derivative, for instance), only measurability is probably too little to get anything useful.

Comment: Does it get any better if the base space can be topologized? In my case, the base space is the unitary dual of a locally compact topological group and is a topological space, say, equipped with Fell topology. It is a measure space equipped with the Plancherel measure.

Comment: @user78032: Is your topological group a real or complex Lie group, or do you also want to allow more general objects, such as p-adic groups?

Comment: @DmitriPavlov My topological group is a 7-dimensional nilpotent real Lie group which is topologically R^7. It's triple central extension of the abelian group of R^4 given in the paper:https://arxiv.org/pdf/1309.7086.pdf

Comment: @user78032: Is the bundle of Hilbert spaces finite-dimensional or infinite-dimensional?

Comment: @DmitriPavlov: Fibres of the bundle are supposed to be the unitary irreducible representation spaces of the of the underlying Lie group. In this case, they are L^2(R^2, dx dy) or L^2(R, dx) depending on which sector of the unitary dual we are choosing.

Comment: Naive question: is this bundle of Hilbert spaces what one gets by disintegrating the left regular rep of G over (some co-null subset of) the unitary dual?

Comment: The accepted answer to the following MO question is probably very relevant to the question you're asking: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/101526/does-it-make-sense-to-talk-about-smooth-bundles-of-hilbert-spaces

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an answer to the refined question formulated in the comments:
the base space is the unitary dual of a Lie group $G$.

The definition can be carried out in the setting of stacks in groupoids (or simplicial sets) on the site of cartesian spaces ($\def\R{{\bf R}} \R^n$ with smooth maps, for all $n≥0$).

Specifically,
we define a stack $R_G$ that gives the unitary dual of a Lie group $G$
and a stack $B_∇$ that gives bundles of Hilbert spaces with connectiom.
Then a morphism $R_G→B_∇$ is precisely a bundle of Hilbert spaces
with connection over $R_G$.

To define the stack $R_G$ that gives the unitary dual of a Lie group,
assign to a cartesian space $T$ the following groupoid $R_G(T)$.

Objects of $R_G(T)$ are given by a Hilbert space $H$ together with a smooth $T$-indexed
family of irreducible unitary representations of $G$ on $H$.
This is simply a smooth map $\def\Hom{\mathop{\rm Hom}} f\colon T→\Hom(G,U(H))$ (landing in irreps), where $U(H)$ is equipped with the ultraweak topology and $\Hom(G,U(H))$ is the space of continuous group homomorphisms equipped with the compact-open topology.  Smooth means that the adjoint map $T⨯G→U(H)$ composed with the inclusion $U(H)→B(H)$ is smooth as a map from a finite-dimensional smooth manifold to a topological vector space $B(H)$.

Morphisms of $R_G(T)$ from $(H,f)$ to $(H',f')$ are given by a smooth map $h\colon T→U(H,H')$ that intertwines the action of $G$.
Here $U(H,H')$ is the topological space of unitary isomorphisms $H→H'$ equipped with the ultraweak topology.

Next, we define stacks $B$ and $B_∇$ of bundles of Hilbert spaces,
(equipped with connection in the case of $B_∇$) as follows.
Given a cartesian space $T$, we define a groupoid $B_∇(T)$ as follows.

Objects of $B_∇(T)$ are pairs $(H,∇)$, where $H$ is a Hilbert space
and $∇\colon T→Hom(T,I(H))$ is a smooth map,
where $I(H)$ denotes the space of unbounded skew-adjoint operators on $H$
(equivalently, one-parameter unitary groups on $H$)
and $\Hom(T,I(H))$ is the space of linear maps $T→I(H)$.

Morphisms of $B_∇(T)$ from $(H,∇)$ to $(H',∇')$ are smooth maps $p\colon T→U(H,H')$
such that $∇'=p^*\theta+\mathop{\rm Ad}_{p^{-1}}∇$, where $\theta$ is the Maurer–Cartan form and Ad denotes the adjoint action.

The stack $B$ is defined analogously, but dropping $∇$ and the condition on $p$.
We have a canonical forgetful map $B_∇→B$.

The obvious forgetful map $W\colon R_G→B$ defines the canonical bundle $W$
over $R_G$.
In particular, the fiber of $W$ of a point of $R_G$ given
by an irreducible representation $ρ$ of $G$ is simply $ρ$ itself.

Now, a connection on $W$ is a lift of the map $W\colon R_G→B$
through the forgetful map $B_∇→B$.

Comment: A naive and basic question: in the setting of the OP's question, what is the space T? How is its smooth structure related to the Fell topology on the usual unitary dual of G?

Comment: On further thought, I see that I have a more basic misunderstanding: it is $R_G$ which is the unitary dual, not any particular $R_G(T)$. But could you include in your answer some indication of how one comes down from the stack $R_G$ to what harmonic analysts usually understand by the unitary dual of a locally compact group?

Comment: @YemonChoi: Fixing $H$ for simplicity and computing any matrix coefficient gives you a smooth function $R_G→{\bf R}$, which establishes a connection to the Fell topology.  (Details need to be checked, of course.)

Comment: @YemonChoi: And points in $R_G$, i.e., isomorphism classes of objects in $R_G({\bf R}^0})$ are precisely points in the unitary dual.

Comment: I'm curious to know why the choice of ultraweak topology. Also, do you have a reference for why that gives a Lie group, so as to get the Maurer–Cartan form?

Comment: @DavidRoberts: Ultraweak topology is the default topology for von Neumann algebras, it is the weak-* topology induced by the predual.  For instance, morphisms of von Neumann algebras are defined as ultraweakly continuous *-homomorphisms, or, equivalently, *-homomorphisms that admit a predual.

Comment: @DavidRoberts: The Maurer–Cartan form on U(H) can be defined directly: to a smooth plot P: T→U(H) we must assign a differential 1-form on T, defined as follows: given a point p∈T with a tangent vector q, consider some curve c: R→T such that c(0)=p, c'(0)=q, and take the derivative of P∘c at 0.

Comment: @DmitriPavlov ah, excellent, thanks!

Comment: @DmitriPavlov: When you're writing the objects of $B_{\nabla}(T)$ as pairs $(H,\nabla)$ do you mean $\nabla: T\rightarrow\hbox{Hom}(\mathcal{G},I(H))$? It occurred to me that it's the Lie algebra $\mathcal{G}$ you wanted to represent as unbounded self-adjoint operators on the Hilbert space $H$.

Comment: @Hasib: No, it's T→Hom(T,I(H)).  The first T gives a point in T, the second T gives a tangent vector at that point.  A connection 1-form sends a point with a tangent vector to an element of the Lie algebra of U(H), i.e., I(H).

Comment: @DmitriPavlov: OK, one final question: In the original problem, the family of the Hilbert spaces was indexed by the unitary dual of the Lie group and as a result the inner product structure of the space of sections of the Hilbert bundle was captured using Plancherel measure on it. Do these features go totally under the rug when you're applying the stacks in groupoid set-up to construct connection on the Hilbert bundle?

Comment: @Hasib: Why would they go under the rug?  The Plancherel measure is still there if you need it.  Recall that π_0(R_G) is precisely the unitary dual of G.  It has a smooth structure inherited from R_G, and also a compatible measurable structure with a canonical Plancherel measure.

Comment: @Dmitry Pavlov: My bad, got it. Thanks a ton.

Comment: @DmitriPavlov. Given that $I(H)$ is not a vector space, what do you mean by a linear map $T \to I(H)$? Also, what does it mean for a map $T\to Hom(T,I(H))$ to be smooth?

Comment: @AndréHenriques: A map T⨯T→I(H) is smooth if the associated map F: T⨯T→Hom(R,U(H)) landing in one-parameter groups of unitaries is smooth, where smoothness can be defined by passing to the adjoint map T⨯T⨯R→U(H).  For linearity in the second argument, we require that for any t, a, b, the one-parameter groups F(t,a), F(t,b), and F(t,a+b) are related by the Trotter product formula.